# Combining rows in Pandas based on a single column when column numbers can change

Tags: python, pandas, row, grouping, aggregation

My problem is something like this:

I have a dataframe say: (column names can change and columns can get added too)

```
 df-in 

     A          B             C           D          E

     U1        1              24          35         a
     V1        9              d           65         j
     V1        85             tv          107        k
     T2        12             7            37        l
     X         8              n           12         uk 
     Y         7              iu          120        pq
     Y         13             k1          77         rp
```

Based on column A, I want to do the following:

If column A values for two rows are the same, I want to merge them into a single row, with values from other columns merged by a comma, else the row remains as is. So, my output data frame should look like this:

```
df-out 

     A          B             C           D          E

     U1        1              24          35         a
     V1        9, 85          d,tv        65,107     j,k
     T2        12             7            37        l
     X         8              n           12         uk 
     Y         7,13           iu,kl       120,77     pq,rp
```

I am still struggling to achieve this. I know if there are fixed columns to the dataframe, we can do something like:

```
df['B'] = df[['A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E']].groupby(['A'])['B'].transform(lambda x: ','.join(x))
```

And go on for other columns, but in my case I can have 100+ columns and many columns can be new, so it is not possible with this route.

Comment: And if you have same `A` value but in non-adjacent rows?

Comment: `df.groupby('A', as_index=False).agg(lambda x: ','.join(dict.fromkeys(x)))`

Comment: to join by consecutive values: `df.groupby(df['A'].ne(df['A'].shift()).cumsum()).agg(...)`

Comment: That will not happen.

Comment: Have you tried `out = df.astype(str).groupby('A', as_index=False).agg(lambda x: ','.join(dict.fromkeys(x)))`? This is doing exactly what you requested

Comment: Thank you @mozway. Sweet. yes thats what I was looking for!